# Configure VPN on ASA to log accounting via NPS

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, radius, accounting, nps

Currently we have VPN setup on an ASA 5510.  I have it set to use NPS for RADIUS authentication, but I've never really configured much as far as accounting.  I'm wanting to set this up to be able to tell more of what people are doing/accessing when they are telecommuting.  I just have it set up pretty basic right now:

```
aaa-server VPN protocol radius
aaa-server VPN host 10.10.4.25
timeout 3
key “password”
authentication-port 1812
accounting-port 1813
radius-common-pw “password”
```

On NPS, under NPS (Local) > Accounting, I see "Configure Accounting", is it that straight forward??

Is there anything else needing done for accounting to be sent to the host 10.10.4.25?  It looks way too straight forward.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if the accounting function will tell you any more than who logged on when...

Answer (score 2):

it's pretty straight forward, you can have it log to a text file, SQL DB or both.  If you choose SQL, make sure you have it failover to a txt file incase the SQL server becomes unavailable.  I think it will deny login requests otherwise.

Me personally, I just rely on the event log, it tells me all the critical info one would probably need.